# Finding position of Object in multidimensional List

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a data structure that is of type `List<List<CustomObject>>`. I want to be able to find the position of a particular `CustomObject` in my data structure. The output would show me the index for e.g. 1,0 which means the `CustomObject` is the 0th element in the 1st list item.

I have thought of the following ways to implement this:

1. Loop through the list one by one and compare the `CustomObject`. Of course i'll have to implement the `equals` method in `CustomObject` to compare.
2. Use the indexOf method to figure out the first index of the data structure which has the `CustomObject`. However in this the parameter to equals would be `List<CustomObject>`.

Are there any other efficient ways to get the index?

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the main  list and call .contains () to check if object is there. If true, use indexOf() to locate it.

You must properly implement equals() and hashcode() in your object .

Answer (score 0):

You can also use .lastIndexOf(Object o) method to get the index of your object directly in one call. This method will give you -1 if that object does not exist in the list.
Check the doc for more detail.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#lastIndexOf(java.lang.Object)

The only issue is this method will give you only the last occurrence of the object. If you have duplicate objects in the list, this will not work.

Also you must properly implement equals and hashcode method for proper comparison to occur.

Answer (score 0):

`indexOf` iterates for you, so 1) and 2) are actually the same. And if the element you're looking for is in the last slot of the last list you iterate over the entire dataset.

To get better then that, you'll have to store the index explicitly in a second datastructure that allows for more efficient searching. Taking the winner in the *"search"* category for datastructures from http://bigocheatsheet.com/ - a `HashMap` in java - you could do it as follows:

In a `HashMap<CustomObject, Index>` you store per object the desired index. That also needs to be updated each time you update the list. Both updating and searching for an item requires only constant time, in other words is independent of the amount of elements you have.

With such a map in place, instead of searching through your list, you'll do `map.get(customObject)` and you'll have the result.

The question for you to answer: can you keep such a datastructure up to date consistently and with less effort than searching in a list. Because if you update your list in a way that affects multiple elements you may loose all benefit due to constantly redoing the entire map.

Besides using multiple datastructures, maybe there is 1 that fits both needs better than a list and a map. But that depends on your data and how you need to access it and which part thereof needs to be optimized.